# Async test wihout Thread.sleep

Tags: java, testing, asynchronous, callback, integration-testing

Currently, I want to verify if the SUT (System under test) is sending properly the requests to external systems. I am using external mocks (via HTTP) and  message queues in QA environment (they can be exchanged by the real systems via configuration).

Problem: to do assertions with those external systems, I am spreading `thread.sleep()` over the integration tests and that is bad. I want to substitute this for a request with *callback* and a test suite that provides a listener for those request. Is there already a solution for this?

Comment: Two tools that might be helpful - [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) and [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit).

Answer (score 1):

For the scenario you describe, I can recommend the use of instances of the class `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` - see the following simple example of a thread doing some calculation asynchronously (here reduced to setting a "percentage done" value first to 50 and then to 100) and allowing the "percentage done" value to be retrieved from the main thread.

Here's the SUT class:

```
public class AsyncProcess implements Runnable {

  private int percentageDone = 0;

  public int getPercentageDone() { return percentageDone; }

  public void doFirstHalf() { percentageDone = 50; }

  public void doSecondHalf() { percentageDone = 100; }

  public void run() {
    doFirstHalf();
    doSecondHalf();
  }

}
```

For unit testing this, I use JUnit 4, with Mockito spies to intercept the two calculation methods of my SUT (alternatively, you can use your favorite AOP framework).

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;

import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class AsyncProcessTest {

  @Test
  public void testExecute() throws Exception {

    final CyclicBarrier firstHalfStarted = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    final CyclicBarrier firstHalfFinished = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    final CyclicBarrier secondHalfStarted = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    final CyclicBarrier secondHalfFinished = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    AsyncProcess process = Mockito.spy(new AsyncProcess());

    doAnswer(new Answer() {
      public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        firstHalfStarted.await();
        invocation.callRealMethod();
        firstHalfFinished.await();
        return null;
      }
    }).when(process).doFirstHalf();

    doAnswer(new Answer() {
      public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        secondHalfStarted.await();
        invocation.callRealMethod();
        secondHalfFinished.await();
        return null;
      }
    }).when(process).doSecondHalf();

    new Thread(process, "AsyncProcess").start();

    assertThat(process.getPercentageDone(), is(0));

    firstHalfStarted.await();
    firstHalfFinished.await();

    assertThat(process.getPercentageDone(), is(50));

    secondHalfStarted.await();
    secondHalfFinished.await();

    assertThat(process.getPercentageDone(), is(100));
  }

}
```

This approach allows for a very fine-grained control of the execution flow of the threads involved. It can easily be extended to a "micro-framework" by encapsulating the pairs of CyclicBarriers and extracting the interception calls as well as support for timeouts and proper exception handling.